# What do the flags 'i', 'ie', 'in', 'n', 'w', 'wi', 'win', 'wn' mean in old FIDE rating lists?

Tags: fide, history, rating

I'm going through some old rating lists
https://ratings.fide.com/download.phtml?period=2001-01-01 to be precise
and came across these flags
**'i', 'ie', 'in', 'n', 'w', 'wi', 'win', 'wn'**

I know that `i = inactive`, `w = woman` and `wi = woman+inactive`
but what do `ie`, `in`, `n`, `win` and `wn` mean. I.e. basically what do the letters `n` and `e` mean?

Comment: The "n" was asked about here: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/21547/in-early-fide-ratings-files-what-does-a-flag-value-of-n-indicate

Comment: Not sure what the "e" stands for, but I note that, like the "n", it also seems to be concentrated on certain countries.